# Circuit paths on a plastic sheet of a Model M keyoard are dark brown and don't forward electric signals any more. Are they corroded?

Tags: keyboard, corrosion

I'm trying to repair a 2015-issue Model M keyoard whose couple of keys don't emit any scancodes any more. After I have excluded some obvious culprits (stuck keys or springs, debris etc.) and disassembled the board (it has already undergone a screw-mod in late 2017 because of broken plastic rivets), I found out that the conductive plastic sheets, which provide all necessary electrical contacts when a key is being typed, have a thin (maybe ¼ mm) layer of dark brown something in the lower left corner. See the images attached.

[image: front conductive sheet]
[image: rear conductive sheet]

I removed the dark brown something (spilled cocoa?) from the sheets, but this did not help me with the dead keys. But I did find out that the conductive strips are partially (in the described area, but also elsewhere) brown instead of white — even in places where I can exclude that any liquid may have trickled into the assembly.

It's the Caps Lock, both keys in row 3 in the block on the left edge, and five keys in the upper function key row (#3, #4, and #8, corresponding to F15, F16, and F20, respectively), which no longer work.

So: What has made the conductive paths brown and probably not conducting? Is this corrosion? And: How can I get rid of this issue? Thank you.

**UPDATE:** See these close-ups of the conductive lines in question:

[image: left lower corner]
[image: bottom part]
[image: controller leads]

**UPDATE #2:** I've now got a vial of conductive silver to apply it to the problematic leads. First I used a multimeter (setting: diode checker) to find out where the broken leads were and applied the silver there. I sometimes had to try even 4 times (and let dry up the varnish, of course) until the multimeter showed me a working lead. But apparently I overdid my work because after reassembly, pressing the 'G' key also gave me 'R' and 'V', and the 'C' key also gave me 'I' and 'O', so that my board has now become pretty useless:

[image: Sheet with problematic leads marked]
[image: Some problematic leads]
[image: Conductive silver applied]

Comment: why does the area of interest fill less than 1% of the image?

Comment: which keys are failing?

Comment: The brown stuff is probably coffee. Need close up photos to tell if the tracks are corroded.

Comment: OK, I've just disassembled the board to make a series of close-ups.

Comment: A search for "model m keyboard repair plastic sheet" will show you how to repair it. Make sure to practise with the conductive paint before trying it on the membrane.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I've alerady read some of the instructions Google spits out, but they mainly concentrate on the notorious plastic rivets. Do you mean something like the CircuitWorks Conductive Pen?

Comment: @Neppomuk Yes, that sort of thing; a different one is suggested in [How to repair a model m membrane](https://deskthority.net/viewtopic.php?t=9072).

Comment: Yes, but the instruction you gave me is focused on broken membranes, not on corroderd conductive lines.

Comment: _"apparently I overdid my work because after reassembly, pressing the 'G' key also gave me 'R' and 'V', and the 'C' key also gave me 'I' and 'O', so that my board has now become pretty useless:"_ - Scrape the paint off and do it again, this time with a very fine paintbrush and just enough paint to wet the bristles. If it runs you have too much. Aim to get the same width as the original traces. Use a head magnifier or 4.5 diopter glasses for greater accuracy. Always let the paint dry thoroughly before testing it.

Comment: I used a fiberglass paintbrush, which came with the silver varnish. It deemed to big, and it disintegrated after an hour of use. Are fiberglass paintbrushes too bad for this application?